# catalyst action accept 0-n args

Tags: perl, catalyst, args

In [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) is there a way to specify that the sub accepts 0-n arguments, say 0-1? so that an action could be something like this:

```
sub add :Local :Args(#between 0 and 1) { 
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    #catalyst code
}
```

I know that something like this could probably be solved with regex somehow, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it by specifying it using the Args action modifier? Thanks!

Comment: You could create a Catalyst::DispatchType subclass to do this, but none seem to exist.

Comment: You could achieve what you want using `:Regex`. Of course, you could also avoid using `:Args` or `:Regex` entirely and throw an error if you got too many args.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're chaining another action from this one, you can drop the `:Args` completely and test yourself whether an argument was provided. From the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~hkclark/Catalyst-Manual-5.9006/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Intro.pod#Action_types):

> No :Args at all means that any number of arguments are taken.